# Do you need a commercial certificate to fly unpaid for a non-pilot owner?

Tags: faa-regulations

Let's say that an aircraft owner is not a pilot and needs someone to fly an airplane for him. If the owner pays 100% of the costs for the flights but does not pay the pilot, does the pilot require a commercial certificate?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking.  Are "he" and "you" the same person?

Comment: Try using "the owner" and "the pilot" instead of "him", "I", and "you".

Comment: I reworded your question to what I *think* you're asking, but if I got it wrong please just rollback or edit again.

Answer (score 1):

This situation would be Illegal as the law stands. What it boils down to is that flight time is considered compensation. [This answer covers it well](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35609/if-flight-time-is-compensation-how-can-a-ppl-holder-legally-fly-at-all) and in your case, since you are not paying your pro-rata share and the owner is paying the full expenses you are in a way getting compensated in flight time.

This [answer is somewhat related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30897/can-a-commercial-pilot-transport-friends-for-free) as well and its seems there needs to be some "common purpose" for everyone on board as well.

Comment: I think there is an important distinction between *"flight time **is** considered compensation"* and *"flight time **may be** considered compensation"*.  Flight time is not automatically classified as compensation; but it can be, if it was a primary motivator for a flight.

Comment: @abelenky I agree and was thinking while I was reading this that a better way to describe it would be that flight time generally provides a benefit to the pilot (particularly if they have a relatively low amount of flight time which needs to be built up in order to be competitive for a job).  The FAA considers this benefit to be compensation if someone else pays for it (exact interpretation is in the linked question, which is really a duplicate).